# Rails Active Storage upload to a public S3 remote url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, ruby-on-rails-5

I need to upload a video to a 3rd party via API.
Using the API I have requested this "Upload Location" which is valid for 15-minute. Now I need to upload my Active Storage video directly to this remote upload location. This remote location is not managed by me.

I have read the official documentation but it's not clear where I can change the default upload location url with this one.
Doc: https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#direct-uploads

Upload location:

```
 {"uploadLocation"=>"https://storage-3rd-party.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/staging/folderr/12345/xxxx?X-Amz-
Security-Token=xxx...."}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you're going to want to implement a custom [ActiveStorage::Service](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activestorage/lib/active_storage/service.rb) for this 3rd party API.  Behind the scenes, [rails invokes `url_for_direct_upload`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activestorage/app/controllers/active_storage/direct_uploads_controller.rb#L17) to get the URL that you're wanting to customize.

You should be able to something close to working if you implemented a new service like so:

```rb
class ThirdPartyStorageService < ActiveStorage::Service

  def url_for_direct_upload(key, expires_in:, content_type:, content_length:, checksum:)
      ThirdPartyAPI.get_upload_location(...)
  end
  
  # Implement other abstract methods...
end
```

You then need to add your service in `config/storage.yml`:

```yaml
third_party:
  service: ThirdPartyStorageService
  # username: ...
  # password: ...
  # other config...
```

And then you can set it up to be used in a specific model, or globally.

```rb
# app/models/my_model.rb
class MyModel
  has_one_attached :file, service: :third_party
end

# or config/application.rb
config.active_storage.service = :third_party
```

It's a bit of work, but I think this should set you up for success!  Make sure to read the [docs on ActiveStorage::Service](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activestorage/lib/active_storage/service.rb#L9-L40) and you can look at the implementations for Azure, AWS and Google storage services for inspiration if you aren't sure how to implement a certain method.